# Emit light from an object

Tags: three.js

I'm making a Three.js scene in which I have stars object and I would like to be able to make them "glow".

By glow I mean make them really emit light not just put a "halo" effect around them.

I tried to put a `PointLight` object at the same position as the star, this make light emit from the object but as you can see, it doesn't make the object "glow" which make a weird effect.
[image]

My current code looks like this:

```
class Marker extends THREE.Object3D {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // load obj model
    const loader = new OBJLoader();
    loader.load(
      "https://supersecretdomain.com/star.obj",
      object => {
        object.traverse(child => {
          if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            // child.material.map = texture;
            child.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
              color: 0xffff00
            });
            child.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
          }
        });
        this.add(object);
      }
    );
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffff00, 0.5, 5);
    this.add(light);
  }
}
```

Any idea of how to do this ? ;)

Comment: How the stars should look like? Could you make a picture with the desired result?

Comment: @prisoner849 The star must glow as if it was a lightbulb. I updated the picture to better show the problem here ;)

Answer (score 5):

Adding a point light to the star is the correct way to make other objects be affected by its light. To make the star itself shine, you can set the [`emissive`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshLambertMaterial.emissive) color of the material to something other than black (for best results, you probably want it to be the same color as the light).

Comment: emissive makes no shine, it just makes the object appear white

Answer (score 2):

In addition to setting up your light, and setting the material emissive property as mentioned by Jave above..

You might want to look into the THREE PostProcessing examples.. Specifically Unreal Bloom pass... If you can get that working, it really sells the effect.

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom.html

Notice how the highlight glow actually bleeds into the scene around the object...

[image]